# Как очистить дату от лишних html оберток (пример внутри)

Tags: php

есть переменная которая содержит дату:

```
$output="<span class="date-display-single __web-inspector-hide-shortcut__" property="dc:date" datatype="xsd:dateTime" content="2016-05-10T09:00:00+03:00">10-05-2016 09:00</span>";
```

задача, состоит в том чтобы очистить ее от html и привести к такому виду:

```
$output="10-05-2016 09:00";
```

подскажите на моем примере, как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
$output = '<span class="date-display-single __web-inspector-hide-shortcut__" property="dc:date" datatype="xsd:dateTime" content="2016-05-10T09:00:00+03:00">10-05-2016 09:00</span>';
$date =  strtotime(strip_tags($output));
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $date);
```

Comment: `echo date("d-m-Y H:i", $date);` Чтобы было как автор просит

Comment: Что бы как автор просит достаточно просто strip_tags без перевода в дату и обратно :)

Comment: да ладно мне потом и переводить понадобится,, благодарю)

Comment: @Mike да, можно и просто strip_tags, но приведение `$otput` к timestamp дает некоторые преимущества - например можно изменить формат отображения даты.

Comment: @Mike Ну там сказано >очистить ее от html и привести к такому виду. Т.е. всё же надо привести к виду :)

Answer (score 1):

Можно вырезать подстроку по маркерам ><
т.е. найти первое вхождение маркера > и выкинуть этот кусок а потом найти маркет < и выкинуть все после него

Comment: по-челочески-то я и сам понимаю, а на php понятия не имею как это сделать, мне бы на php

Comment: именно ваш вариант интересовал, ответ ниже конечно самый короткий и не требующий усилий, но больше интересно, как заменить строку, если она начинается на "иван" и заканчивается на "иванов"

Answer (score 1):

От противного. Так как формат даты известен, то не убираем теги вокруг нее, а ищем дату регулярным выражением. Например так `\d.-\d.-\d{4} \d.:\d.`

Comment: а вот такой вариант как можно провернуть? тоже интересно просто как заменить строки, если они начинается на "иван" и заканчивается на "иванов", на "просто строка"

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/hW2vO8/1 - для поиграться